# why are these rings equal ? Z+...

Tags: ring-theory

i am sorry for my English. 
i saw both two rings are equal in the book but i dont know why. Please can anyone explain why ? or is it true ?

$Z + 7Z\sqrt{98}=Z+7Z\sqrt{2}$

And also is this true ?     $Z+7Z\sqrt{2}=Z+Z\sqrt{98}$

Comment: I think you mean *isomorphic*, not equal.

Comment: They are not isomorphic: the square of $7\sqrt{2}$ is $98$, while in ${\bf Z}+7{\bf Z}\sqrt{98}$ there is no element whose square is $98$. It's supposed to be ${\bf Z}+{\bf Z}\sqrt{98}$ on the left hand side.

Comment: @tomasz, what does that have to do with isomorphism? The *groups* $\;\Bbb Z\;$ and $\;3\Bbb Z\;$ are isomorphic though the second one has no element which is the positive square root of $\;4\;$ , say...

Comment: Second one is true because $\sqrt{98} = 7\sqrt{2}$...

Comment: @DonAntonio: but this question specifically asks about *rings*...

Comment: Still, @Thomas. I just gave an example from group theory. The fact that one ring has an element that the other one doesn't have doesn't not *necessarily* mean they can't be isomorphic...though in this case it may mean so, but that requires a proof.

Answer (score -1):

Hinty without words (assuming there's no $\;7\;$ in your left side):

$$\sqrt{98}=7\sqrt2$$

Comment: in the book it says they are equal, not isomorphic.

Comment: @user104847, then either you wrote a superfluous $\;7\;$ in the left side or else the book is wrong. For example: $$0+7\sqrt2\in\Bbb Z+7\Bbb Z\sqrt2$$ but $$0+7\sqrt2\notin \Bbb Z+7\Bbb Z\sqrt{98}=\Bbb Z+49\Bbb Z\sqrt2$$

Comment: @user104847 : just making sure we talk about the same thing, "$=$" is equal while "$\cong$" is isomorphic.

Comment: Yes, it is @user88595

Comment: @user104847: In which book did you see this? Could you add a screenshot to your question?